# casting date within a to_char function?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I cast a date or timestamp column to date within a to_char function?

```
to_char(date_column, 'YYYY'-'MM) as year_month_col
```

But I need to cast the date_column to date first but am unsure

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TO_CHAR`, as you are using it above, appears to be Oracle code.  MySQL uses the `DATE_FORMAT` function:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%Y-%m') AS year_month_col
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: thanks, so I dont need to cast the date_column to date just to be safe ?

Comment: @Chris90 Well you _could_ use `DATE(date_column)` which would certainly give you a date.  But, if you want to view the date in the _format_ of `YYYY-MM`, then use `DATE_FORMAT`.